# Asymptotic Growth: Understanding the specific proof of f(n) + little o(f(n)) = theta (f(n))?

Tags: algorithm, performance, time, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I'm working through proof of `f(n) + o(f(n)) = theta (f(n))` and I came across a part in the proof that I am having trouble understanding.

We let `f(n)` and `g(n)` be asymptotically positive functions and assume `g(n) = O(f(n))`.
In the proof, it states that since we know that `f(n) + g(n) ≥ f(n)` for all `n`, we can conclude that `f(n) + g(n) = Omega((f(n))`.
We can also conclude similarly that `f(n) + g(n) ≤ 2 f(n)`. Therefore `f(n) + g(n) = O(f(n))`. 
I am having trouble understanding why it is the case that `f(n) + g(n) = Omega((f(n))` and `f(n) + g(n) = O(f(n))` would be true. How is it that we can prove that the tight-lower bound is specifically when we add `g(n)` to `f(n)`? What is it that we are exactly concluding from the value of `g(n)`?

Comment: not sure it is a question for SO. try asking it here https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of proving that `f(n)` is `theta(g(n))` is to prove two separate statements: that `f(n)` is `omega(g(n))`, and `f(n)` is `O(g(n))`. It's pretty clear this way of proving is correct from the definitions of those notations.

In this exact problem, if we choose some constant `c` to be equal to `1`, we will have, for every `n`, that `f(n) + g(n) >= c * f(n)`, so that, by definition, shows that `f(n) + g(n)` is `Omega(f(n))`. Furthermore, for the `O(f(n))` part, if we choose the constant `c` to be `2` in this case, we need to prove that there exists some `n0` such that `f(n) + g(n) <= c * f(n)` for every `n > n0`, which is equivalent to `g(n) <= f(n)` for every `n > n0`, which is equivalent to the definition of `g(n) = O(f(n))` given in the problem statement.

Hope this helps.